# Is It Possible to do this T-SQL Query with LINQ (to Entities)

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to write the following LINQ-Entities query:

> Get a list of Questions, that have been answered, ordered by most recently answered

So, basically it's a 1..* between Question and Answer.

So i tried to write the query in SQL first, so that i understood it, and here's what i came up with:

```
WITH [Answers] AS
(
    SELECT      QuestionId,
                CreatedOn,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (                        
                    PARTITION BY QuestionId
                    ORDER BY    CreatedOn DESC
                ) As [Rank]

    FROM    dbo.Answers
)

select a.*
from dbo.questions a
inner join answers on a.questionid = answers.questionid
where answers.rank = 1
order by answers.createdon desc
```

Now, i have no idea if it's even possible to do this with LINQ.

Of course, that query above might be the wrong way to go about it, so don't think of this as a simple T-SQL to LINQ-Entities translation.

I'm just looking for a way to write a LINQ-Entities query for the above requirement.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
var query = questions
              .Where(q => q.Answers.Any())
              .OrderByDescending(
                q => q.Answers.OrderByDescending(
                  a => a.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault());
```

Just hopeful i guess. Following error received:

> DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
>   Parameter name: key

**EDIT**

I should also mention that i need to **eager load** the `Answers` in the final result set, e.g:

```
return ctx.Questions.Include(q => q.Answers)
```

Comment: i think its not possible because of partition by clause

Comment: @Pranay - as i said, it doesnt have to be a straight conversion. I'm wondering if it can be done with a LINQ aggregate operation (e.g group by)

Comment: @RPM1984 does my new query work for you?

Comment: @Hasan Khan - trying it now. Because your using anonymous type projection (fine), i'm losing the eager loading (`.Include`). This is a EF4 thing.. so im trying to figure out how to also include the Replies in the final result set. Maybe you can help?

Comment: @RPM1984 I'm not using anonymous types you're probably talking about someone else's answer. My answer can support Include()

Comment: @Hasan - no, talking about yours. Your not using anon types, but your still using projections. If i put a `Include` in your query, it doesnt return the answers. (they are `null`), which doesnt mean they dont have answers, it means it hasnt been eager loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from question in context.Questions
where question.Answers.Any()
let max = question.Answers.Max(a=>a.CreatedOn)
orderby max descending
select question
```

EDIT: since you want to eager load answers; you might want to either resort to doing this entire query in SQL Server and exposing it to EF as a stored procedure or you might want to add LastAnswerOn column in questions table. This will make your query much more efficient and simple and you will be able to use it in EF without problems.

Comment: RE your edit. I'm trying to avoid using a stored procedure, because i'm using paging with LINQ, which is really versatile. The LastAnswerColumn would need a trigger on answers table to keep updating it. Not ideal, but it's an option.

Comment: You can also do it in data access code by updating LastAnswerColumn every time an answer is added.

Comment: yep, i'm actually leaning that way now. Just because i dont want to do paging with SQL Server (don't know how, or if it's possible)

Comment: went with the cache field for last answered. Also accepting since if it wasnt for the eager loading issue, this answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Replace that FirstOrDefault which does not make sense with First. Or Replace entire sub-query with Max (on date). It should work.

Good luck with EF, it is so broken ;-) In many cases where Linq To Sql would work, with EF I had to give up and fetch the data and do the computation locally.